# How to get Adobe Reader full path(including executable file name)?

Tags: c#, adobe-reader

it's possible? I need to get the full path of Adobe Reader including the executable name. I'm looking for on windows registries, the closer that I did was found the full path without executable name. Thanks in advance.

my code:

```
var adobe = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Adobe").OpenSubKey("Acrobat Reader");
var version = adobe.GetSubKeyNames().First();
var path = adobe.OpenSubKey(version).OpenSubKey("installer").GetValue("path");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of these should do it for you:

```
    var adobe = Registry.LocalMachine
                        .OpenSubKey("Software")
                        .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
                        .OpenSubKey("Windows")
                        .OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
                        .OpenSubKey("App Paths")
                        .OpenSubKey("AcroRd32.exe");

    var path = adobe.GetValue("");

    var adobeOtherWay = Registry.LocalMachine
                                .OpenSubKey("Software")
                                .OpenSubKey("Classes")
                                .OpenSubKey("acrobat")
                                .OpenSubKey("shell")
                                .OpenSubKey("open")
                                .OpenSubKey("command");

    var pathOtherWay = adobeOtherWay.GetValue("");
```

Pick one and run with it ;)

Comment: No problem, just mark my answer as correct and I can go to sleep! :)

Comment: Wait... Is the "AcroRd32.exe" default name of Adobe Reader independent version,architecture etc?

Comment: I'm running  Windows 7 64 bit right now and it matches my old XP x86 machine.  So I assume it's OK.  If you have ANY trouble give me a shout and I'll write something a bit more complex to fix it.  But I really don't think you'll have any issues!

Comment: Plus, don't forget you have my second solution which doesn't require the "AcroRd32.exe" usage anyway!

Comment: and I'm on a 32bit machine,have same name. Well.. seems default. Anything, I will back here. :) Have a good night, man. :)

Comment: That was a slow response!  But cool, it's the better way IMHO.

Comment: I said this because I have no sure if  `AcroRd32.exe` is compatible with older versions, unlike 'anotherway`. If I'm wrong, tell me please.

Comment: I don't know for SURE that the AcroRd32.exe way is compatible.  You made the right choice, the adobeOtherWay method was the right choice.. It's the safest option!

Comment: On Windows Server 2003, the registry path is Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe

Answer (score 5):

I found a problem with the "adobeOtherWay" solution. If Adobe Acrobat(not reader) is installed, then the path will point to Acrobat.exe and not the reader's exe.(I wanted to comment to above, but don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\Adobe\Acrobat\Exe
It gives me the full path and exe- name of the installed Acrobat Reader, just what you need.

Comment: This works if Acrobat Reader is the default PDF viewer. If Adobe Acrobat (ie: the paid version) is the default, it appears in this key instead.